# Yii and YiiBooster widget modal confirm to url

Tags: yii

Using the yiibooster modal widget, I want it to go to a different url if user clicks ok to confirm.

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Restart Game',
    'type'=>'warning',
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'onclick'=>'js:bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?",
        function(confirmed){console.log("Confirmed: "+confirmed);})'
    ),
));

//this is the url i want it to go to when ok confirmed is clicking
'url' =>array('site/restart?gameId='.$gameRecord->id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('site/restart', array('id'=>$gameRecord->id));

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Restart Game',
    'type'=>'warning',
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
       'onclick'=>'js:bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?",
             function(confirmed){
                if(confirmed) {
                   window.location = "'.$url.'";
                }
             })'
        ),
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it be this:

`'url'=>array('site/restart', array('id'=>$gameRecord->id))`

Assuiming you have or need the rules in the config?